# Angular Pipe; Array of Objects and objects include Array

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe

After unsuccessfully customizing answers of similar questions, i unfortunately need some help.

I'm trying to use an angular pipe to filter following data structure:

```
subjects = [
      { name: "subject1", keywords:["keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"]},
      { name: "subject2", keywords:["keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"]},
    ];
```

I tried to customize an example with a simple data structure:

```
subjects = [ "subject", "subject2"]
```

and following pipe :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'SearchPipe'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, input: any): any {
   if (input) {
     return value.filter(val => val.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
   } else {
     return value;
   }
  }
}
```

but can not figure out, how to adopt it to my use case.

The goal is to filter the data by  keyword and show the matching name:

Edit:
HTML Template:

```
    <div class="welcome-content" fxFlex="80">
        <div class="search-container">
            <mat-form-field class="textfield" appearance="standard">
                <mat-label>z.B. Flugverspätung</mat-label>
                <input class="input" matInput [(ngModel)]=subject>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="subject-container">
            <div class="subject-list">
                 <div class="subjects" *ngFor="let subject of subjects | SearchPipe: subject">
                    <div class="subject-wrapper">
                        <a mat-button class="control-button" (click)="goToChat(subject)">{{subject.name}}</a>               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I`m thankful for any tips.

Comment: did you added your pipe among the `declarations` property in you `NgModule`? Also, notice that the name is `FilterPipe`, not `SearchPipe`.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
Yes i added the pipe to the declarations. The pipe is properly named in my code, i just did a wrong copy. (will edit the question). The pipe works fine, with the described simple data structure.

Comment: val.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase(), you missed name key inside filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing your implementation, noticed that the `value` itself is the array given in the `ngFor`. A better approach to accomplish with your current data structure would be:

```js
transform(values: any[]) {
    return values.filter(value => {
        // Validates that has a keywords filter array
        if (value && value.name && value.keywords) {
            // If there's any matching, then return the value
            return value.keywords.some(kw => {
                return value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(kw.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            }) && value;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Here's a quick update based on the input field.

First, you used the same name as in the for, nothing wrong, but wont work in the pipe due to scope (see that it's used right next to the pipe as an argument). That said, you **must** create a string property that's binded to the input field, I named this as `textSubject`, you can name it as you want.

```html
<input class="input" matInput [(ngModel)]="textSubject">
...
<div class="subjects" *ngFor="let subject of subjects | SearchPipe: textSubject">
    <div class="subject-wrapper">
        <a mat-button class="control-button" (click)="goToChat(subject)">{{subject.name}}</a>               
    </div>
</div>
```

So, now you must have a second argument in the `transform` function which is the value of the input (`textSubject` in this case).

```js
transform(values: any[], input: string) {
    return values.filter(value => {
        if (value && value.keywords && input) {
            // If matches, then return the value
            return value.keywords.some(kw => {
                return input.toLowerCase().indexOf(kw.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            });
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

I tried your solution, but it does not search in value.keywords for matching pairs, just in value.name.

Maybe i have to add that there will be a textfield, in which you type the search value. This search value is used to look for matches in value.keywords.

Comment: may you put the template/value of the text field?

Comment: i edited the question and added the associated html template

Comment: did an updated based on the input field @Crobrg

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much, this works pretty well. @E. Mancebo

In addition, i added some code to return values with partly matching strings:

`
  transform(values: any[], input: string): any {
    return values.filter(value => {
      if (value && value.keywords && input) {
          // If matches, then return the value
          return value.keywords.some(kw => {
            
            if(kw.includes(input.toLowerCase())){
              return kw.indexOf(kw.toLowerCase()) >=0;
            }    
          });
      } else {
          return value;
      }
  });
}
`

Comment: if this answer is ok to you @Crobrg please mark it.